# Check if user has liked a post or not with Facebook Graph API

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, feed

I want to design a news feed with fully functioning likes/Unlike ,share and commenting,and of course fetching recent posts from users newfeed.Now here is the thing,I want to check whether a user has liked a post (type is video, photo, link or status).

If a user has liked the post already, then show unlike button, if a user has not liked, show like button.

FILES:

[index.php](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B63GOnae39s1WHF5eklNWkdjWTQ/edit?usp=sharing) click to open the file

Now there are few problems here:
1- problem is that when ever i run this code,it shows only one post from newsfeed.but if i remove the following code from the code,it will fetch 20 posts from newsfeed .i dont know whats happening.

```
$ret = $facebook->api(array(
'method' => 'fql.query',
'query' => "SELECT like_info FROM $type WHERE object_id=$object_id"
 ));
 $checklike = $ret['data']['like_info']['user_likes'];
```

2-we can use object_id only for photos,albums,and videos.but you cant use it to get like_info fro link and status types.so i need new way and a new technique to findout wether user has liked an post or not

3-whenever i add a new $facebook->api() inside the foreach loop,it will fetch 1-3 posts from fb or even not all.

so if you could find anyway to make a news feed with fully functioning likes/Unlike ,share and commenting,and of course fetching recent posts from users newfeed OR fixing the problems i mentioned ,That would be greatful.

please help me as soon as possible,if you need anything ,just comment and i will provide you with.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`data` is an array, edit your code to-

```
$checklike = $ret['data'][0]['like_info']['user_likes'];
```

or loop around each object, if you are expecting more than one result like:

```
foreach($ret['data'] as $data)
 echo $checklike = $data['like_info']['user_likes'];
```

**UPDATE**

The latest version of Graph API today is v2.8. In this version you can get the reactions also. It is better to use reactions than likes as reactions also includes the Love, WOW and HAHA etc reactions which likes does not.

You can add the field for reactions's summary instead of likes's summary as below
`fields=reactions.limit(0).summary(true)`

Using this you will get the reactions summary as below

```
"reactions": {
        "data": [
        ],
        "summary": {
          "total_count": 6,
          "viewer_reaction": "LOVE"
        }
      }, ......
```

Notice the `"viewer_reaction": "LOVE"` which means you have given a reaction to the post which is LOVE. It's value could be any one of  `LIKE, LOVE, HAHA, WOW, SAD, ANGRY, NONE`. The `NONE` means you have not liked the post.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18215412/how-can-i-like-an-post-using-graph-api

Answer (score 0):

Here are solutions to a couple of your problems:

**Problem:** is that when ever i run this code,it shows only one post from newsfeed.but if i remove the following code from the code,it will fetch 20 posts from newsfeed. I don't know whats happening.

```
$ret = $facebook->api(array(
'method' => 'fql.query',
'query' => "SELECT like_info FROM $type WHERE object_id=$object_id"
 ));
 $checklike = $ret['data']['like_info']['user_likes'];
```

**Answer:** Above code is filtering your contents, here you are checking whether your each of the 20 posts (which you are pulling) and looping individually and checking if it is a status, photo, video, link, etc is liked by the logged in user or not? Above query works only for type = Photo,type = Link, as far as I remember only Photos, Links have like_info object, you need to refer to FQL docs though. For posts other than Photos,links use this query:

```
SELECT like_info FROM stream WHERE post_id ='$id'
```

For more info you can check it here - `https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql`

**Problem**: we can use object_id only for photos,albums,and videos.but you cant use it to get like_info fro link and status types.so i need new way and a new technique to find out whether user has liked an post or not

**Answer**: Use stream table, for like_info.

**Problem**:-whenever i add a new $facebook->api() inside the foreach loop,it will fetch 1-3 posts from Facebook or even not all.

**Answer**: I didn't get this one?

**Edit:**

Can you show me an example for issue #3

Comment: lets forget about the 3rd error for now.i get this error for fql:   https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B63GOnae39s1VEZpVHlGMjc2MWs/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: And also when i tried it with $id ($post['id']) inside my code,it will not bring any data,and i tried to paste one of my post ids from one of my actual profile statuses ,it prints out this :https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B63GOnae39s1Nk5oelBLVjdXcFk/edit?usp=sharing